# Handling onBackPressed in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have some issues navigating from a list in a Fragment to its detail fragment.

This is my hierarchy:

```
MainActivity (with NavigationDrawer)
              |
  ----- WrapperFragment-----
      |                 |
RequestsFragment   DetailFragment
      |
RequestListFragment
```

In other words, Wrapperfragment is the Fragment set by the NavigationDrawer.
Inside this there is RequestsFragment which contains a ViewPager with several RequestListFragments.
By clicking on an item, DetailFragment should be the active fragment. By pressing back, you should be taken to RequestListFragment.

Basically, I just want to have a list that supports selecting an item, navigating to its DetailFragment and back-navigating by pressing back.
This is why I built the Wrapper, which should exchange the fragments.

This is my Code:

WrapperFragment:

```
public void setList() {
  ...
  getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.request_wrapper, listfragment)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
}

public void setDetail() {
  ...
  getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.request_wrapper, detailfragment)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
}
```

When I click on a listitem, I see the DetailFragment, but pressing back closes the application instead of taking me back to ListFragment.

Can you guys please help me?

Thank you!

P.S.: I am using the support library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because back goes to the previous Activity not Fragment, and there is none. You'll have to handle the back press manually by capturing it like so;

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Or like so;

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Relating to your question you could use this code to manually pop the Fragments backstack.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // if there is a fragment and the back stack of this fragment is not empty,
    // then emulate 'onBackPressed' behaviour, because in default, it is not working
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    for (Fragment frag : fm.getFragments()) {
        if (frag.isVisible()) {
            FragmentManager childFm = frag.getChildFragmentManager();
            if (childFm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                childFm.popBackStack();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: I just went with using another Activity which shows the details. For me it is a more natural flow. Nevertheless, your answer does it, too.